# Поделитесь своим опытом логирования больших проектов

Tags: python, логирование

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, как вы организуете работу с логированием (модель logger).

Предположим у меня есть средних размеров проект

```
Module 1
    - file 1.py
    - file 2.py
Module 2
    - file 1.py
    - file 2.py
    - file 3.py
main.py
config.py
```

В разных файлах есть свои классы, там есть поле logger. И я использую функцию настройки логеров:

```py
def config_logger(logger):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(LOGS_DIR + 'script.log', encoding='utf-8')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

По сути я хочу, чтобы логеры в разных файлах писали данные в один файл. При этом данные из сторонних библиотек мне там не нужны. Также, хотелось бы писать в один файл и при каждом запуске программы стирать предыдущие данные.

Сейчас у меня следующая проблема, чтобы выполнить эти условия, мне приходится сначала открывать и затирать файл в main.py: `open(LOGS_DIR + 'script.log', mode='w').close()`. Иначе не получается.

Есть подозрения, что я в целом неверно подхожу к логированию. Потому, буду рад любым советам и примерам, как вы подключаете логи к своим проектам.

Comment: У вас довольно общий вопрос. Чтобы лог охватывал весь проект, пусть каждый класс принимает его как параметр. Для очистки лога при каждом запуске надо указать `mode`: `FileHandler(filename, mode='w')`.

Comment: Про очистку знаю, но если в моем коде так сделать, то при каждой настройке логера файл стирается (то есть после объявления в каждом классе). Передавать как параметр в каждый класс можно конечно, но мне не хотелось бы ради лога скармливать каждому классу дополнительный параметр.

Comment: А что в этом такого плохого? Взамен вы получаете более гибкую систему логгирования, которая настраивается в одном месте. А все пользователи этой системы вообще не должны знать, куда они пишут (файл, консоль, сетевой сокет) - для них это просто обобщенный вывод.